# CSS+ HTML (Insert picture in the right corner)

Tags: html, css

```css
@font-face { 
  font-family: Droid Sans; 
    src: url('../fonts/DroidSans-webfont.eot'); 
    src: local("Droid Sans"), url('../fonts/DroidSans-webfont.woff'); 
} 

@font-face { 
  font-family: Jenna Sue; 
    src: local("Jenna Sue"), url('JennaSue-webfont.ttf'); 
} 

@font-face { 
  font-family: News Cycle; 
    src: local("News Cycle"), url('NewsCycle-Regular.ttf'); 
} 

html { 
  height: 100%;
}

* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* tell the browser to render HTML 5 elements as block */
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { 
  display:block;
}

body { 
  font: normal .85em 'Droid Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #434434;
  color: #E6EEB0;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

p { 
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

img { 
  border: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
  font: normal 400% 'Jenna Sue', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0 0 0px 0;
  padding: 20px 0 5px 0;
}

h1 { 
  color: #C0CB77;
}

h2 { 
  font: normal 220% 'Jenna Sue', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
}

h3 { 
  font: normal 125% 'trebuchet ms', arial, sans-serif;
}

h4, h5, h6 { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  font: normal 110% arial, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

h5, h6 { 
  font: italic 95% arial, sans-serif;
  color: #888;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

h6 { 
  color: #362C20;
}

a, a:hover { 
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #FFF;
}

a:hover { 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

ul { 
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li { 
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin: 0 0 0 0; 
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
}

ol { 
  margin: 8px 0 22px 20px;
}

ol li { 
  margin: 0 0 11px 0;
}

#main, header, #logo, nav, #site_content, footer { 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}

#main { 
  width: 950px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

header { 
  width: 950px;
  height: 105px;
}

#logo { 
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

#logo h1 { 
  font: normal 400% 'Jenna Sue', arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 40px 0 0 17px;
  color: #FFF;
}

#logo h1 a { 
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logo h1 a:hover { 
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav { 
  height: 26px;
  width: 720px;
  margin: 1px auto 0 auto;
  float: right;
  padding: 35px 0 0 0;
} 

#site_content { 
  width: 950px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 4px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #565747;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
} 

#sidebar_container { 
  float: right;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 450px;
}

#content { 
  text-align: justify;
  width: 444px;
  padding: 0 0 5px 30px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

#content ul { 
  margin: 2px 0 5px 0px;
}

#content ul li { 
  list-style-type: none;
  background: transparent url(../images/bullet.png) no-repeat left center;
  margin: 0 0 0 0; 
  padding: 2px 0 2px 28px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#blog_container h4 {
  font: normal 250% 'Jenna Sue', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;}

#blog_container h4.select {
  width: 475px;}

.blog {
  background: url(../images/calendar.png) no-repeat;
  width: 54px;
  height: 46px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.blog h2 {
  font: normal 90% arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #FFF;
}
  
.blog h3 {
  font: 130% arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: none;
  margin: -19px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222;
}

footer { 
  width: 950px;
  font: 109% 'Droid Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 17px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center; 
  background: #6F7640;
}

footer p { 
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

footer a, footer a:hover { 
  color: #E6EEB0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover { 
  color: #E6EEB0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* form styling */
.form_settings { 
  margin: 0;
}

.form_settings p { 
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.form_settings span { 
  padding: 5px 0; 
  float: left; 
  width: 170px; 
  text-align: left;
}
  
.form_settings input, .form_settings textarea { 
  padding: 4px; 
  width: 252px; 
  font: 100% arial, sans-serif;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C0CB77; 
  background: transparent;
  color: #E6EEB0;
}
  
.form_settings .submit { 
  font: 140% 'News Cycle', arial, sans-serif; 
  border: 0; 
  width: 100px; 
  margin: 0 0 0 162px; 
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 0 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer; 
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  background: #6F7640;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.form_settings textarea, .form_settings select { 
  font: 100% 'Droid Sans', arial, sans-serif; 
  border: 1px solid #C0CB77; 
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.form_settings select { 
  width: 304px;
}

.form_settings .checkbox { 
  margin: 4px 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  width: 14px;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
}

ul.images {
  width:450px;
  height:450px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
} 

ul.images li {
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  list-style:none;
}
 
ul.images li.show {
  z-index:500;  
}
 
ul img {
  border:none;  
}



/* from here: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers */
.lavaLampWithImage {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 10px 5px 15px 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.lavaLampWithImage li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.lavaLampWithImage li.back {
  background: #63604F;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  height: 28px;
  z-index: 8;
  position: absolute;
}

.lavaLampWithImage li a {
  font: 109% 'Droid Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 6px 9px 0 9px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto 10px;    
}

.lavaLampWithImage li a:hover, .lavaLampWithImage li a:active, .lavaLampWithImage li a:visited {
  border: none;
}

.curlycontainer{
border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
margin-bottom: 1em;
width: 466px;
}

.curlycontainer .innerdiv{
background: transparent url(images/brcorner.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
position: relative;
left: 2px;
top: 2px;
padding: 1px 4px 15px 5px;
}

a.css3dbutton {
    background: darkred; /* background color of button */
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 28px Arial; /* font size and style */
    position: relative;
  top: 0; /* anchor main button's position */
    bottom: -12px; /* Depth of 3D effect. :after pseudo element inherits this value so it's animated in Chrome. See: kizu.ru/en/pseudos */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -15px 5px darkred inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -15px 5px darkred inset;
    box-shadow: 0 -15px 5px darkred inset;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

a.css3dbutton, a.css3dbutton:after {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px; /* vertical and horizontal padding of button */
    -moz-border-radius: 8px/15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px/15px;
    border-radius: 8px/15px;
    outline: none;
}

a.css3dbutton:after { /* pseudo element to construct 3D side of button */
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: inherit; /* Inherit main button bottom value to animate it. See: kizu.ru/en/pseudos */
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #6e0e0c; /* background color of 3D effect */
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 3px gray;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 3px gray;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 3px gray;
}

a.css3dbutton:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 25px 5px rgba(182, 64, 61, 0.7) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 25px 5px rgba(182, 64, 61, 0.7) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 25px 5px rgba(182, 64, 61, 0.7) inset;
    background: #bc3835; /* background color when mouse rolls over button */
}

a.css3dbutton:active {
    top: 12px; /* shift button down 12px when depressed. Change 12px to match button's "bottom" property above */
    bottom: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -20px 5px darkred inset, 1px 1px 2px #eee;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -20px 5px darkred inset, 1px 1px 2px #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 -20px 5px darkred inset, 1px 1px 2px #eee;
}

 a.button{
  background: #ECECEC;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#7f7f7f;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #fff;
  border:1px solid #a7a7a7;
  width: 145px;
  margin:0px auto;
  margin-top:100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px white inset, 0px -2px 8px white, 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 8px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition:box-shadow 0.5s;
 }
 a.button i{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
 }
 a.button:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px white inset, 0px -2px 20px white, 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 8px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 }
 a.button:active{
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0px -2px 20px white, 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d1d1d1 0%,#ECECEC 100%);
 }

hr{

border: 0; border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc; background: #999;

}
.styled-button-8 {
 background: #25A6E1;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#25A6E1),color-stop(100%,#188BC0));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
 filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#25A6E1',endColorstr='#188BC0',GradientType=0);
 padding:8px 13px;
 color:#fff;
 font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
 font-size:17px;
 border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 border:1px solid #1A87B9
}
.display_img{
float: right; 
}
```

This is my code where I print content.

```
   <?php
    echo"<div id=\"content\">";
    echo"</div>";
    ?>
```

[image: Web page]

**I'd like to add profile picture in a empty place (as seen in the picture) ,but how to move it to the right?**

Here is a css of div content.

EDIT:

I want to move picture to right side (Shown in a picture where to)
[Move right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcIXI.jpg)

Comment: You, want to move it to right, but you're floating it to left. Also, the outer quotation of the echo must be single quotation (' '), the inner ones for the id will be double quotations as they are. Try that and let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: @Dania I don't want to move everything. I want to keep text in left side and insert picture in right side (at the empty place as shown in the picture).

Comment: Give your image a class or id, and float it to right. This way it should move to the right of the div in which it is included.

Comment: It's still not moving to the right side. It's on the left. <div id="display_img"><img src="images/mot.gif" alt="moteris"/></div>

Comment: I said give your image a class not your div. Like this, <div><img src="images/mot.gif" alt="moteris" class="display_img"/></div>

Comment: @Dania I edited my post with a .css code.

Comment: @Dania ,works fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: Good, then please accept the answer. You're welcome :)

Comment: @Dania, can you please tell me how? I'm new here. I'd like to close this question.

Comment: You can find the close option bellow the question post itself, just beside the edit option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your image a class or id, and float it to right. This way it should move to the right of the div in which it is included. For example, give it a class named display_img and float it to right, like this:

```
.display_img{
float: right; 
}
```

Another trick can be the following:

```
.display_img{
    margin-right: 0; 
    /*you can keep the float here if you want, but it will not affect the results adversely if removed*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:right;` for your profile picture.And `float:left;` for the rest of the content in your div.Instead of using `float:left;` as an overall for all your content in the div.

Comment: I didn't work. I want to keep my text in left side and insert a profile picture in a empty place as seen in picture.

Comment: @KriukriuSidenica  I made some edit to the code,check it out.

Comment: Should to make new div for picture? img  {
    float: right;
}

Comment: @KriukriuSidenica Yeah, that can work although you could just add the `float:right` to the image tag.`<img src="...."  style="float:right" ..........`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, If I get your point correctly, but you can try something like this:

```
<span>Skelbimas</span>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>Miestas</td>
    <td rowspan="5">Insert Picture</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Vardas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Telefono</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>El Pastas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Arnzius </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```